# Print a div using javascript in angularJS single page application

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, printing, single-page-application

I have a single page web application using angularJS. I need to print a div of certain page.
I tried the following:

The page contains few div (print.html)

```
<div>
  <div>
    Do not print
  </div>
  <div id="printable">
    Print this div
  </div>
  <button ng-click="printDiv('printableArea');">Print Div</button>
</div>
```

The controller has following script:

```
$scope.printDiv = function(divName) {
    var printContents = document.getElementById(divName).innerHTML;
    var originalContents = document.body.innerHTML;        
    document.body.innerHTML = printContents;
    window.print();
    document.body.innerHTML = originalContents;
}
```

This code prints the desired div but there is a problem. 
the statement `document.body.innerHTML = originalContents;` replaces the body of the whole application since it is a SPA. So when I refresh the page or click on print button again, the whole content of the page is erased.

Comment: Please include a fiddle.

Answer (score 90, accepted):

```
$scope.printDiv = function(divName) {
  var printContents = document.getElementById(divName).innerHTML;
  var popupWin = window.open('', '_blank', 'width=300,height=300');
  popupWin.document.open();
  popupWin.document.write('<html><head><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" /></head><body onload="window.print()">' + printContents + '</body></html>');
  popupWin.document.close();
}
```

Comment: All `$http` requests brakes after this... :( Also I can't to reload page... only copy url to new tab works... I can't to understand why..

Comment: The same here, all $http request brakes but only happen with Chrome when I close the new window. Firefox or IE works well

Comment: I found why is not working this solution, here is the answer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23071291/javascript-window-print-in-chrome-closing-new-window-or-tab-instead-of-cancel

Comment: Why does he get  var originalContents = document.body.innerHTML; he doesn't use originalContents anywhere

Comment: Is there any function like this for specific div convert and download as pdf file?

Comment: This works great for me except it leaves a window open containing the document after I click "Print" or "Cancel" in the print dialog. Is it possible to close that window after printing or canceling?

Comment: Popup not closed after print.

Comment: The above solution worked, however the styles like font color and div background colors are not being printed as on screen! any suggestions?

Answer (score 11):

Two conditional functions are needed: one for Google Chrome, and a second for the remaining browsers.

```
$scope.printDiv = function (divName) {

    var printContents = document.getElementById(divName).innerHTML; 

    if (navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('chrome') > -1) {
        var popupWin = window.open('', '_blank', 'width=600,height=600,scrollbars=no,menubar=no,toolbar=no,location=no,status=no,titlebar=no');
        popupWin.window.focus();
        popupWin.document.write('<!DOCTYPE html><html><head>' +
            '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />' +
            '</head><body onload="window.print()"><div class="reward-body">' + printContents + '</div></body></html>');
        popupWin.onbeforeunload = function (event) {
            popupWin.close();
            return '.\n';
        };
        popupWin.onabort = function (event) {
            popupWin.document.close();
            popupWin.close();
        }
    } else {
        var popupWin = window.open('', '_blank', 'width=800,height=600');
        popupWin.document.open();
        popupWin.document.write('<html><head><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" /></head><body onload="window.print()">' + printContents + '</body></html>');
        popupWin.document.close();
    }
    popupWin.document.close();

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Why do you have `onbeforeunload` and `originalContents`?  Also, you are missing the `</body>` tags from the `popupWin.document.write` lines.

Comment: Very nice thank you, just a unused variable: `originalContents`

Answer (score 7):

You can now use the library called [angular-print](https://github.com/samwiseduzer/angularPrint)

Comment: This library is in flux, I'd be careful about using it in production until some of the issues get resolved

Comment: @G.Mart Apparently the author is pushing a [major release](https://github.com/samwiseduzer/angularPrint/issues/7#issuecomment-163067195) this weekend solving the cross-browser compatibility

Comment: From the author, 3 days ago:

"Yeah, I'm really sorry for the lack of updates on multi-browser compatibility. I anticipate releasing a new version this weekend that supports chrome, mozilla and safari. Edge will be mostly supported, but may still have a bug or two.chrome, mozilla and safari. Edge will be mostly supported, but may still have a bug or two."

Comment: So unfortunately no reference of IE, and edge will be a tossup.

Answer (score 1):

I done this way:

```
$scope.printDiv = function (div) {
  var docHead = document.head.outerHTML;
  var printContents = document.getElementById(div).outerHTML;
  var winAttr = "location=yes, statusbar=no, menubar=no, titlebar=no, toolbar=no,dependent=no, width=865, height=600, resizable=yes, screenX=200, screenY=200, personalbar=no, scrollbars=yes";

  var newWin = window.open("", "_blank", winAttr);
  var writeDoc = newWin.document;
  writeDoc.open();
  writeDoc.write('<!doctype html><html>' + docHead + '<body onLoad="window.print()">' + printContents + '</body></html>');
  writeDoc.close();
  newWin.focus();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me in Chrome and Firefox! This will open the little print window and close it automatically once you've clicked print.

```
var printContents = document.getElementById('div-id-selector').innerHTML;
            var popupWin = window.open('', '_blank', 'width=800,height=800,scrollbars=no,menubar=no,toolbar=no,location=no,status=no,titlebar=no,top=50');
            popupWin.window.focus();
            popupWin.document.open();
            popupWin.document.write('<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title>TITLE OF THE PRINT OUT</title>' 
                                    +'<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="app/directory/file.css" />' 
                                    +'</head><body onload="window.print(); window.close();"><div>' 
                                    + printContents + '</div></html>');
            popupWin.document.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay i might have some even different approach.

I am aware that it won't suit everybody but nontheless someone might find it useful.

For those who do not want to pupup a new window, and like me, are concerned about css styles this is what i came up with:

I wrapped view of my app into additional container, which is being hidden when printing and there is additional container for what needs to be printed which is shown when is printing.

Below working example:

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
 app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  
    $scope.people = [{
      "id" : "000",
      "name" : "alfred"
    },
    {
      "id" : "020",
      "name" : "robert"
    },
    {
      "id" : "200",
      "name" : "me"
    }];

    $scope.isPrinting = false;
  $scope.printElement = {};
  
  $scope.printDiv = function(e)
  {
   console.log(e);
   $scope.printElement = e;
   
   $scope.isPrinting = true;
      
      //does not seem to work without toimeouts
   setTimeout(function(){
    window.print();
   },50);
   
   setTimeout(function(){
    $scope.isPrinting = false;
   },50);
   
   
  };
    
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

 <div ng-show="isPrinting">
  <p>Print me id: {{printElement.id}}</p>
    <p>Print me name: {{printElement.name}}</p>
 </div>
 
 <div ng-hide="isPrinting">
    <!-- your actual application code -->
    <div ng-repeat="person in people">
      <div ng-click="printDiv(person)">Print {{person.name}}</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  
</div>
```

Note that i am aware that this is not an elegant solution, and it has several drawbacks, but it has some ups as well:

- does not need a popup window
- keeps the css intact
- does not store your whole page into a var (for whatever reason you don't want to do it)

Well, whoever you are reading this, have a nice day and keep coding :)

**EDIT:**

If it suits your situation you can actually use:

```
@media print  { .noprint  { display: none; } }
@media screen { .noscreen { visibility: hidden; position: absolute; } }
```

instead of angular booleans to select your printing and non printing content

**EDIT:**

Changed the screen css because it appears that display:none breaks printiing when printing first time after a page load/refresh.

visibility:hidden approach seem to be working so far.

Answer (score -3):

**I don't think there's any need of writing this much big codes.**

I've just installed angular-print bower package and all is set to go.

***Just inject it in module and you're all set to go
Use pre-built print directives & fun is that you can also hide some div if you don't want to print***

http://angular-js.in/angularprint/

Mine is working awesome .

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, provide answers that [don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but I think answer is much accurate.
And it works 100%.

Comment: There is also already an answer that is basically the same as yours, so yours doesn't add anything new to this thread. I would say even that other answer is invalid though as it is _only a link to an external source_ which could be off topic, and if that link breaks your answer and their answer are both broken because your answer IS the link.

Comment: this is very foolish