# Getting $scope.$digest error in chrome

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome, angularjs-scope

I am facing very strange issue in Chrome,

In my application i am printing receipt in other window using

Window.open();
Window.print();

However if user ignore opened window and click on print button again then i am getting following error.

line no 9 contains **print function from my.js**

`1.       Error: [$rootScope:inprog] $apply already in progress
   2.       http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.16/$rootScope/inprog?p0=%24apply
   3.       at http://localhost:62344/external/angularJS/1.2.16/angular.js:78:12
   4.       at beginPhase (http://localhost:62344/external/angularJS/1.2.16/angular.js:12720:15)
   5.       at Scope.$apply (http://localhost:62344/external/angularJS/1.2.16/angular.js:12509:11)
   6.       at HTMLInputElement.<anonymous> (http://localhost:62344/external/angularJS/1.2.16/angular.js:18626:21)
   7.       at HTMLInputElement.jQuery.event.dispatch (http://localhost:62344/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.js:3063:9)
   8.       at HTMLInputElement.elemData.handle.eventHandle (http://localhost:62344/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.js:2681:46)
   9.       at Scope.$scope.print (http://localhost:62344/Scripts/app/my.js:5044:34)
   10.      at http://localhost:62344/external/angularJS/1.2.16/angular.js:10567:21
   11.      at http://localhost:62344/external/angularJS/1.2.16/angular.js:18627:17
   12.      at Scope.$eval (http://localhost:62344/external/angularJS/1.2.16/angular.js:12412:28)`

On other browsers its working fine.

Any inputs ??

-Thanks,
Yogesh

Comment: Without having a look at the code or anything...if you wrap the code in your print button function with the following code it might prevent the error. `if ($scope.$root.$$phase != '$apply' && $scope.$root.$$phase != '$digest') {
    //Your code
}`

Comment: you are calling an apply somewhere in the stack that is causing this issue. It is likely that it is being called to low in the stack, and as @user1135469 suggest you might need to call the apply method safely. There are several ways to accomplish this. Showing us some more code would help.

Comment: I have tried this but still have issue.. if ($scope.$root.$$phase != '$apply' && $scope.$root.$$phase != '$digest'). In this solution i have found that $scope.$root.$$phase always remains "$apply".

Answer (score 0):

Problem is with chrome. we have solved this issue using following solutions

[Print a div using javascript in angularJS single page application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22189544/print-a-div-using-javascript-in-angularjs-single-page-aplication)

[Javascript window.print() in chrome, closing new window or tab instead of cancelling print leaves javascript blocked in parent window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23071291/javascript-window-print-in-chrome-closing-new-window-or-tab-instead-of-cancel)