# How to Print and export kendo-grid data in angular js?

Tags: angularjs, printing, kendo-grid, export-to-excel, alasql

i am trying to add two functions to my project. One is to export the grid data as its views to an excel (i am using ***kendo-grid*** and the grid data has been formatted from the UI side) and the second one is to print the grid data with the grid lines.
i have added both, but i am having two problems.
 1. Exporting to excel with the numbers formatted. i used this example http://jsfiddle.net/agershun/00nfeq12/

```
alasql('SELECT x [No.],Type,Amount INTO XLSX("Type.xlsx",{headers:true}) FROM ?',[  $scope.data.Data]);      

    };
```

$scope.data.Data is a result of the api. So it contains the actual data. But in my grid, i have added custom formatting.

2. printing with the grid lines.
   I am using this example.
   [Print a div using javascript in angularJS single page application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22189544/print-a-div-using-javascript-in-angularjs-single-page-aplication)

but the print just shows the data, no border lines and these are needed.

How do i solve this please?
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**How to export to Excel and keep custom formatting?**

You can write your own formatting function, for example round number to 2 digits:

```
alasql.fn.myfmt = function(n) {
     return Number(n).toFixed(2);
}

alasql('SELECT name, myfmt(amt) INTO XLSX("john.xlsx",{headers:true}) \
      FROM ?',[$scope.items]);
```

See the example [at jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/agershun/awwx208t/1/)

**How to print Kendo UI grid?**

You can read and try the example how to print fron Kendo UI grid in [this article](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/web/grid/print-export).

Comment: is there a way to export the detail grid also to he same excel with this?

Comment: You can use "sourcefilename" and "range" parameters. Please, see thiis example: https://github.com/agershun/alasql/blob/master/test/test251.js

Comment: What is it that it does?  can you please explain a bit

Comment: And i want to mention the detail grid comes from another data source than the master one