# window.print() doesn't print anything in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, window

I'm working on an `AngularJS` application and I want to print the view. So I'm I've used the `window.print()` function, and it does give me the opportunity to print, however nothing shows in the print. How can this be?

My view.controller

```
angular.module('app')
.controller('viewController', ['$scope', '$state', '$interval', '$window', 'view', 'socketService', function ($scope, $state, $interval, $window, view, socketService) {
    ...
    $scope.print = function () {
        console.log('content is printed');

        window.print();
    };
    ...
}]);
```

the view.html

```
...
<table class="table table-striped table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td ng-repeat="value in values">
                <h3>
                    {{ value.shownName | capitalize }}
                </h3>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="item in items">
            <td ng-repeat="value in values">
                {{ findMatch(item, value.matchValue) }}
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<div class="viewNavigation">
    <!-- Print -->
    <a href class="btn btn-default" ng-click="print()" ng-show="viewFunctions.print"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-print"></i> Print</a>

    <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: **[Some help you could get](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22189544/print-a-div-using-javascript-in-angularjs-single-page-aplication)**

Comment: @GuruprasadRao: Thanks ^^ I've looked at similar solutions, however all of them prints the content on a single line, and not as specified in the `view.html`.

What I'm looking for is just to call the print function which can be found in most browsers.