# print the content of a HTML DIV

Tags: html, angularjs

I want to print a content of a html div and currently i am using this code.

```
<div id="content">
</div>

var printContents = document.getElementById("content").innerHTML;
var originalContents = document.body.innerHTML;

document.body.innerHTML = printContents;
window.print();
document.body.innerHTML = originalContents;
```

printing is working correctly. But after that my other functions are stop responding. I'm using angular.js.

any idea?

Comment: I don't think so. The user marked it as the solution, which might mean some other users might not find the answer using the same keywords.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the answer I found

HTML and JS CODE

```
 <div id="printable">
    Print this div
  </div>
  <button ng-click="printDiv('printableArea');">Print Div</button>


$scope.printDiv = function(divName) {
  var printContents = document.getElementById(divName).innerHTML;
  var popupWin = window.open('', '_blank', 'width=300,height=300');
  popupWin.document.open();
  popupWin.document.write('<html><head><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" /></head><body onload="window.print()">' + printContents + '</body></html>');
  popupWin.document.close();
}
```

I found it from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22189544/print-a-div-using-javascript-in-angularjs-single-page-aplication)

Comment: Thank you very much @The Mechanic !!!

Comment: The above solution worked, however the styles like font color and div background colors are not being printed as on screen! any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

if you are using angularjs 
use

```
<div ng-bind-html="content |trustAs">
</div>
```

in your controller

```
$scope.content='<div> Your html</div>';  

app.filter('trustAs', ['$sce', 
        function($sce) {
            return function (input, type) {
                if (typeof input === "string") {
                    return $sce.trustAs(type || 'html', input);
                }
                console.log("trustAs filter. Error. input isn't a string");
                return "";
            };
        }
    ]);
```

[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ebinmanuval/z632eh9e/)

You can also use ng-sanitize to get the same result https://stackoverflow.com/a/25679834/3769965

Comment: are you sure this will print the div?

Comment: you need to use trust as filter or ng-sanitize to get the result. updated the answer