# Print a HTML page using Window.print

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I have been trying to get this done from long. I have a HTML page with few icons and upon clicking print I want the page to be printed including the icons.

I did as per the solution suggested in the [Print specific `div`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22189544/print-a-div-using-javascript-in-angularjs-single-page-aplication)

But in this I am not able to load the icons and also the page formatting goes haywire. Any suggestions on how to get the page printed upon click without having to play around with the already formatted/styled page.

The application has a cshtml file which has the styles, icons referenced which again need not be referenced to in each html page I create. So when I call `window.print()` the styles are not loaded as that specific `div` which I want to be printed, does not load the icons which the action is called for. My question is in such case where the styles are defined once for the entire application, how do I call the `window.print()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var win = window.open('','printwindow');
    win.document.write('<html><head><title>Print it!</title><link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost:8080/fin/pcd/css/printlib.css" type="text/css" /><link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css" type="text/css" /></head><body>');
    win.document.write($("#"+divid+"key").html());
    win.document.write($("#"+divid2+"line").html());
    win.document.write('<div class="testPrint"></div><script>;</script></body></html>');
    win.print();
```

Using above you can print specific divs and import css where you can apply necessary styles(including your icons) to the div.

**Some more info added:**

Check the below working example link you would get some idea: https://plnkr.co/edit/f1JkCgYvI10rsdm5msmM?p=preview

**Note:** if `background-color` is given to the css of the page to be printed the concerned attribute would only work if `background graphics` is enabled for `chrome` and is not needed for other browsers.

```
Check below image on how to enable background graphics in chrome:
```

[image]

Comment: It is a very big application and each page does not have a `head` or `title` or `body`. Each page has a set of `divs` and the style sheets are declared in a common file. Would this approach still work ?

Comment: offcourse think of the page to print as html page where you can for example write tiles or templates or stuff and everytime you just change the content and write css wisely.

Comment: the solution you  gave does not give me a solution to the issue that I have been facing. I have a cshtml file in which all the styles have been defined and mentioning that in the js file did not pull me the styles/icons that I wanted to load upon click.

Comment: once you get new tab that has everything to print check the html structure over there and write css accordingly. moreover background graphics of browsers by default is disabled enable them. Check the plnkr I have added in the above updated answer.